# It's possible migrate windows generated from netbeans into Window Builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, windowbuilder

I need to migrate some swing-based projects in the netbeans, with windows  generated by GUI-Builder, to Eclipse, but Window Builder can't generate the screen design by reading .java files created by netbeans.

Is it possible to have the Window Builder render correctly the screens created in the Gui-Builder of the netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. Using a GUI builder locks the code into that IDE, and that GUI builder. This is one of a number of reasons that experienced GUI developers advise not to use them.

Comment: So... I have to build the screens from scratch to be able to use in eclipse?

Comment: Sure, but once you've developed them in pure Java code ('from scratch') they will be editable in whatever IDE you or the others working on the code, choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure but when you go to **File** there is an option to **Export Project**. Try that, it could work but again I am not sure. I am new to Netbeans